# Using sed to change only consecutive repeated letters

Tags: text, sed

Using sed, how to change the letter 'a' to 'A' but only if it appears repeated as two or more consecutive letters. Example, from:

```
galaxy
ear
aardvak
Haaaaaaaaa
```

into

```
galaxy
ear
AArdvak
HAAAAAAAAA
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using groups. If you have this file:

```
$ cat a
galaxy
ear
aardvak
Haaaaaaaaa 
Ulaanbaatar
```

You can use this sed command:

```
$ sed 's/\(.\)\1\{1,\}/\U&/g' a
galaxy
ear
AArdvak
HAAAAAAAAA 
UlAAnbAAtar
```

What does happen here? If we have a char, "packed" in a group (`\(.\)`), and this group (`\1`) repeats itself one or more times (`\1\{1,\}`), then replace the matched part (`&`) by its uppercased version (`\U&`).

Comment: Thanks!! The idea of using `\1` already in the first part of the `s` command is nice and unusual.

Comment: @strapakowsky I know! I forget it is possible with some frequency, for example. Actually, I just remembered it now, after some years, reading your question :D

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**
You can do this with:

```
sed 's/a\(a\+\)/A\U\1/;s/b\(b\+\)/B\U\1/;s/c\(c\+\)/C\U\1/;s/d\(d\+\)/D\U\1/;s/e\(e\+\)/E\U\1/;s/f\(f\+\)/F\U\1/;s/g\(g\+\)/G\U\1/;s/h\(h\+\)/H\U\1/;s/i\(i\+\)/I\U\1/;s/j\(j\+\)/J\U\1/;s/k\(k\+\)/K\U\1/;s/l\(l\+\)/L\U\1/;s/m\(m\+\)/M\U\1/;s/n\(n\+\)/N\U\1/;s/o\(o\+\)/O\U\1/;s/p\(p\+\)/P\U\1/;s/q\(q\+\)/Q\U\1/;s/r\(r\+\)/R\U\1/;s/s\(s\+\)/S\U\1/;s/t\(t\+\)/T\U\1/;s/u\(u\+\)/U\U\1/;s/v\(v\+\)/V\U\1/;s/w\(w\+\)/W\U\1/;s/x\(x\+\)/X\U\1/;s/y\(y\+\)/Y\U\1/;s/z\(z\+\)/Z\U\1/'
```

(Thanks to *shelter*)

Or with a pipe of sed:

```
function capitalize_consecutives () {
  sed 's/a\(a\+\)/A\U\1/' |
  sed 's/b\(b\+\)/B\U\1/' |
  sed 's/c\(c\+\)/C\U\1/' |
  sed 's/d\(d\+\)/D\U\1/' |
  sed 's/e\(e\+\)/E\U\1/' |
  sed 's/f\(f\+\)/F\U\1/' |
  sed 's/g\(g\+\)/G\U\1/' |
  sed 's/h\(h\+\)/H\U\1/' |
  sed 's/i\(i\+\)/I\U\1/' |
  sed 's/j\(j\+\)/J\U\1/' |
  sed 's/k\(k\+\)/K\U\1/' |
  sed 's/l\(l\+\)/L\U\1/' |
  sed 's/m\(m\+\)/M\U\1/' |
  sed 's/n\(n\+\)/N\U\1/' |
  sed 's/o\(o\+\)/O\U\1/' |
  sed 's/p\(p\+\)/P\U\1/' |
  sed 's/q\(q\+\)/Q\U\1/' |
  sed 's/r\(r\+\)/R\U\1/' |
  sed 's/s\(s\+\)/S\U\1/' |
  sed 's/t\(t\+\)/T\U\1/' |
  sed 's/u\(u\+\)/U\U\1/' |
  sed 's/v\(v\+\)/V\U\1/' |
  sed 's/w\(w\+\)/W\U\1/' |
  sed 's/x\(x\+\)/X\U\1/' |
  sed 's/y\(y\+\)/Y\U\1/' |
  sed 's/z\(z\+\)/Z\U\1/' 
}
```

Then let it parses your file:

```
capitalize_consecutives < myfile
```

`\U` is to UPPERCASE the occurence. I guess this is only for GNU sed.

Comment: \U works in other seds. The order might be different, i.e. `\1\U`. Good luck to all.

Comment: Also, you don't need all those pipes, just do `sed 's/a../../;s/b.../.../;.....'` Good luck to all.

Comment: It's a pity that you removed answer with 25 pipes.

Comment: LOL. 25 pipes are fun!. Thanks for including my option. To make it legible, it is perfectly fine to put each `s/a.../A.../` on separate lines, all surrounded by just one set of single-quotes. Good luck to all.