# What other parameters other than \U does sed have?

Tags: sed

I already knew `sed`'s `\1`, `\2`, ... , `\n` and [recently discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899545/using-sed-to-change-only-consecutive-repeated-letters) that it has a useful `\U` option to create uppercase. What other such useful 'backslash options' exist besides `\U`?

I have checked `sed` man page but found no reference to it there.

Comment: Which sed are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite possibly you want one of these fine GNU sed document sections:

- [Backreferences, in regular expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Backreferences_002c-in-regular-expressions-103)
- [GNU Extensions for Escapes in Regular Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Escapes)

Answer (score 7):

According to the links [CodeGnome](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1301972/codegnome) passed, those are:

`\L`
    Turn the replacement to lowercase until a \U or \E is found,

`\l`
    Turn the next character to lowercase,

`\U`
    Turn the replacement to uppercase until a \L or \E is found,

`\u`
    Turn the next character to uppercase,

`\E`
    Stop case conversion started by \L or \U.