# capitalize names having international letters like éèàö

Tags: sed, locale, capitalize

My [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) attempts on RHEL 6.3:

```
$ export LC_ALL=fr_FR.utf-8
$ sed 's/ \([a-zA-Zé]\)\([^ ]*\) /[\u\1\L\2\E] /g' <<< " hélène  NOËL  étienne "
 hélène  NOËL  étienne

$ export LC_ALL=C
$ sed 's/ \([a-zA-Zé]\)\([^ ]*\) /[\u\1\L\2\E] /g' <<< " hélène  NOËL  étienne "
[Hÿlÿne] [Noÿl] [ÿtienne]

$ sed --version
GNU sed version 4.2.1
[...]
```

**Is [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) able to output the following?**

```
[Hélène] [Noël] [Étienne]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this ok for you?

```
kent$  echo " hélène  NOËL  étienne "|sed -r 's/(\S)(\S+)/[\U\1\L\2]/g'
 [Hélène]  [Noël]  [Étienne]
```

my sed version is abit different from yours, but I think the line should run there too:

```
kent$  sed --version |head -1
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
```

added my locale settings, you may want to know:

```
kent$  echo $LANG
en_US.utf8

kent$  locale
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Thanks Kent. Please could you add explanation about `-r` and `\S` meaning (you may provide some links). Do you know the difference between locales `en_US` and `en_US.utf8`? Do you have any clue why the [tag:sed] script did not work using `en_US.utf8` locale? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

[Kent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19033090/938111) did not solve my issue but I have not provided him all my constraints. My [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) input file is like:

```
sfou;STéphane Foù - stephane.fou@example.com;;
fbar;frédéric bâr - frederic.bar@example.com;;
hnoel;Hélène NOËL - helene.noel@example.com;;
```

The [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) script shall capitalize the names only:

```
sfou;Stéphane Foù - stephane.fou@example.com;;
8945;Frédéric Bâr - frederic.bar@example.com;;
hnoel;Hélène Noêl - helene.noel@example.com;;
```

---

**Based on [Kent's help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19033090/938111), I successfully passed this script:**

```
LC_ALL=fr_FR sed -r 's/(\w)(\w*) /\U\1\L\2 /g' test.cvs
```

---

Other locales do not give the right result:

```
$ LANG=fr_FR.utf8 LC_ALL= sed -r 's/(\w)(\w*) /[\U\1\L\2] /g' test.cvs
sfou;STé[Phane] Foù - stephane.fou@example.com;;
fbar;frédé[Ric] bâ[R] - frederic.bar@example.com;;
hnoel;Hélè[Ne] NOË[L] - helene.noel@example.com;;

$ LANG=C LC_ALL= sed -r 's/(\w)(\w*) /[\U\1\L\2] /g' test.cvs
sfou;STé[Phane] Foù - stephane.fou@example.com;;
fbar;frédé[Ric] bâ[R] - frederic.bar@example.com;;
hnoel;Hélè[Ne] NOË[L] - helene.noel@example.com;;

$ LANG=en_US.utf8 LC_ALL= sed -r 's/(\w)(\w*) /[\U\1\L\2] /g' test.cvs
sfou;STé[Phane] Foù - stephane.fou@example.com;;
fbar;frédé[Ric] bâ[R] - frederic.bar@example.com;;
hnoel;Hélè[Ne] NOË[L] - helene.noel@example.com;;
```

Locales `en_US`and `fr_FR` (without `.utf8`) are OK:

```
$ LANG=en_US LC_ALL= sed -r 's/(\w)(\w*) /[\U\1\L\2] /g' test.cvs
sfou;[Stéphane] [Foù] - stephane.fou@example.com;;
fbar;[Frédéric] [Bâr] - frederic.bar@example.com;;
hnoel;[Hélène] [Noël] - helene.noel@example.com;;

$ LANG=fr_FR LC_ALL= sed -r 's/(\w)(\w*) /[\U\1\L\2] /g' test.cvs
sfou;[Stéphane] [Foù] - stephane.fou@example.com;;
fbar;[Frédéric] [Bâr] - frederic.bar@example.com;;
hnoel;[Hélène] [Noël] - helene.noel@example.com;;
```

Note: I have discovered `\w` from [CodeGnome's links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10905904/938111).