# sed: selectively change/preserve case of regex matches (backreferences)?

Tags: regex, sed, case-sensitive, backreference

I have never been able to find out how, when using 'sed', to limit changing the character case of a particular buffered output. For example, in the following 'sed' command I have two selected two spans of text to save as buffers to re-use during substition:

```
sed -ri 's/^<div class="line" data-line-mode="verse"><span class="speaker"[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/span>[ ]*(.*)[ ]*$/<p class="psi"><font size="-1" color="green"><b>\U\1<\/b>:<\/font><br>\n\2<br>/' "$f"
```

The desired output then is:

```
<p class="psi"><font size="-1" color="green"><b>FIRST_BUFFER_OUTPUT_ALL_UPPERCASE<\/b>:<\/font><br>\nSecond_buffer_output_originalCase<br>
```

But what I always end up with is:

```
<p class="psi"><font size="-1" color="green"><b>FIRST_BUFFER_OUTPUT_ALL_UPPERCASE<\/B>:<\/FONT><BR>\nSECOND_BUFFER_OUTPUT_ORIGINALCASE<BR>
```

So everything after the '\U\1' in the command gets its case altered to UPPERCASE, including tag chars. Is there a way to limit '\U\1' to altering only the contents of buffer '\1' to UPPERCASE, leaving everything else as typed?

Comment: To demonstrate the issue more succinctly: `sed -r 's/(A)(b)/\U\1\2/' <<<'Ab'` yields `'AB'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10906194/1258041), try `\E` to stop case conversion started by `\L` or `\U`:

```
sed -ri 's/^...$/...\U\1\E<\/b>:<\/font><br>\n\2<br>/' "$f"
                         ^^
```

Comment: +1; since it's the original case the OP wants for the 2nd match, `\E` is solution here; from the linked page: `\E Stop case conversion started by \L or \U.`