# Using sed to change only consecutive repeated letters, general case

Tags: text, sed

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899545/using-sed-to-change-only-consecutive-repeated-letters) I asked how to do this but the special case of capitalization led to a solution that is also special case because it allows the use of `/u`. So here I ask more generally. I discovered that I have to use this with different cases, not only capitalization.

Using `sed`, how to change the letter 'a' to 'cool' but only if it appears repeated as two or more consecutive letters. Example, from:

```
galaxy
ear
aardvak
Haaaaaaaaa
```

into

```
galaxy
ear
coolcoolrdvak
Hcoolcoolcoolcoolcoolcoolcoolcoolcool
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lev got the example right. Prince John gave the general case but got the formula wrong and with one extra step.

After some test and thoughts, merging the two we've got:

```
l='a'    #search string
r='cool' #replacement string
sed "s,$l$l,$r$r,g ; s,$r$l,$r$r,g," inputFile
```

Test it and tell me, it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The deleted answer almost solves it:

```
sed 's/aa/coolcool/g; s/coola/coolcool/'
```

If one doesn't know the letter to substitute, it gets more challenging.
I was only able to come up with the quite frightening and self-repeating

```
sed '/\([[:alpha:]]\)\1/ {h; s/.*\([[:alpha:]]\)\1.*/\1/; x; s/\([[:alpha:]]\)\1/coolcool/g; G; s/cool\(.\)\(.*\)\n\1/coolcool\2/; s/\n.*//}'
```

This changes

```
galaxy
ear
bbrdvak
Haaaaaaaaa
```

(note the third word) to

```
galaxy
ear
coolcoolrdvak
Hcoolcoolcoolcoolcoolcoolcoolcoolcool
```

Comment: +1. Sed program needs more slashes. Also, see if you can throw in a branch to a label called `:`, that always baffles people.

Comment: @TomAnderson I just heard using `-r` was considered "not cool" around here. Am I mistaken? In my understanding, that way it's guaranteed to work on any version.

Comment: `-r` is a seductive mistress. It makes writing the program easier, but it does make it less portable. Although in my experience, a GNU sed invocation using `-r` will work with BSD (well, OS X) sed if you change the flag to `-E`. The language those flags enable is the same. All in all, i like using `-r`/`-E`, but avoid them if i know i need maximum portability.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's;aa;coola;g;s;aa;cool;g;s;coola;coolcool;g' inputFile
```

In general,

#### bash

```
l='a' #search string
r='cool' #replacement string
sed -r "s;$l$l;$r$l;g;s;$l$l;$r;g;s;$r$l;$r$r;g" inputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed ':a;s/\(a\|cool\)a/coolcool/g;ta' file
```

or more generally:

```
sed ':a;s/\(a\|\n\)a/\n\n/g;ta;s/\n/cool/g' file
```